# Change <menu> height with jquery when page width is less than 960px

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, height, width

How can I use jquery to change the height of the element  when the page width is less than 960px

This is what I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ( $(window).width() < 960) {
    $('menu').animate({height:'60px'});
}
else {
    $('menu').animate({height:'40px'});
}

});
```

but it only works when you refresh the page and I want it to work if the page is re-sized once the page has loaded.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('menu').animate({height:'60px'});
    ^^^^
 here is the error if menu is `id` than should be `#menu` if `class` than `.menu`
```

menu tag browser support

> [image]

Comment: I am not using the class or id menu, but the tag <menu>

Comment: @user1691862 please check the reason in the answer

Comment: Well I tried with using #menu with <div id="menu"> but still no dice

Comment: @user1691862 please provide the [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so we can solve

Answer (score 2):

You need to post the HTML to be sure, but `$('menu')` is not typically a valid selector, it will match an element like `<menu>`. More likely it is either a class or id - if it is a class it should be `$('.menu')` and if it's an ID it should be `$('#menu')`

To run when the page is resized, wrap your code in the `resize()` method - http://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
// resize menu depending on page width
function do_resize(){
    if ( $(window).width() < 960) {
        $('menu').animate({height:'60px'});
    } else {
        $('menu').animate({height:'40px'});
    }
}
// resize menu on initial page load
$(document).ready(do_resize);
// resize menu when page is resized
$(window).resize(do_resize);
```

Comment: I am using the element <menu> and it works, but only page loads. I want the height to change if the page size changes once loaded